# download a webpage with curl failed (getting captcha response) while other downloaders succeed

Tags: python, web, curl, download

is there anyway to download this web page using curl or python urllib

https://www.crunchyroll.com/en-gb/blood-blockade-battlefront/episode-6-get-the-lock-out-754075

because i get Cloudflare CAPTCHA html response "8 kb file"
but if i use a different downloaders like KGet or idm i get the actual html file "131 Kb file size"

i can open this link on any browser and never ask for captcha
i tried also to use the full headers from the browser with curl command with no success

what could be the reason for this behaviour, in other words what is missing in curl request that triggers captcha on server side? where idm and KGet has no problem

I also used the same headers used by KGet with curl with no success

any help would be appreciated

sample of received html content using curl "captcha":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
```

Comment: I'm guessing the page/Cloudflare is detecting that it's coming from an automated source and giving you the captcha instead of the page to prevent a (D)DOS attack. The people who own the site probably only want humans using the page, not automated agents.

Comment: but why other downloaders like idm and KGet have no problem

Comment: what is missing in curl request that triggers captcha on server side?

Comment: These systems are often fickle in who they let by and who they request a captcha on. Without knowing the specifics of idm and Kget, it's hard for me to say.

Comment: In general cloudflare goes by ip reputation. If this is coming from a datacenter it will get blocked for example.